# How to respect DEFAULT values when using JOOQ generated UpdatableRecordImpl from() method

Tags: java, mysql, jooq, jooq-codegen

It seems that there had been some work to respect default values when using DAO inserts/updates here: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2700.

This is great, however I'm struggling  to take advantage of this when also using the generated `from` method on the `UpdatableRecordImpl`. Specifically, when generating an `UpdatableRecordImpl`, we are provided a `from` method to convert from an entity which implements the record interface to the record, however, if you use this method, DEFAULT fields will not be supported since the `from` method sets all fields on the entity, including the ones which should be defaulted, and when they are unset, they'll be set to null on the record.

For example, if we have a table fruit, with a single column

```
alter table fruit
    add column color varchar(6) not null default 'red';
```

JOOQ would generate an interface `IFruit` with getters/setters on a field `color`. Then we would have a `FruitRecord` class generated which extends `UpdatableRecordImpl<FruitRecord>` with a `from` method like the following:

```
@Override
public void from(IFruit from) {
    setColor(from.getColor());
}
```

If we make use of this `from` method, color will be explicitly set to `null` **if it has not been set in the from object**. When that happens, when the record is inserted it will fail because color can't be null and won't make use of the default color. If the field was not set at all in the record object, I believe JOOQ would handle that field in a way that it would make use of the DEFAULT value, and therefore insert it properly with the default.

I haven't dug into the complete depths of these generated classes and such, and perhaps I'm missing something, but would there be an existing way to make use of this `from` method in a way that unset/null fields are distinguished from each other to take advantage of DEFAULT values?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Bug

That's a bug in jOOQ 3.17 and less: [#14727](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/14727). It will be fixed in jOOQ 3.18. It's related to a combination of:

- Having `NOT NULL` columns
- Using `<interfaces>true</interfaces>` in the code generator (which generates this slightly optimised method)
- As you observed, that method doesn't expose the expected behaviour, from `Record.from(Object)`, which violates the Liskov principle

### Workarounds

The workaround for bug [#14727](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/14727) is to manually upcast the type to `Object`, to avoid calling the generated method:

```java
IFruit f = ...
record.from((Object) f);
```

Alternatively, you can reset all changed flags on the `Record`, maybe even globally, using a `RecordListener`